# App or command line program for searching and downloading torrents and subtitles, for multiple search terms / shows / files, all at one go

Tags: bittorrent, subtitles

I am looking for an app for that can do all of the following:

1. Search for both torrents and subtitles at the same time on the web for a drama, movie etc. based on keyword
2. Use BitTorrent protocol to download the actual file from the torrent file

The user should not need to search for the torrent file, then separately download the actual file, then separately search for a subtitle file. All this should be done by the program and the user just needs to initiate the process by typing in the show name, and then, with a click or a press of a button, and after waiting for the download to happen, the show files and its subtitles will be in the user's file directory, ready to be watched.

In addition, the app should be able to read from a txt or csv file, or a Google spreadsheet, which holds a list of show names, and do all the above for a batch of shows, and not just one. Bonus but not required feature: if possible, the app should allow the user to prioritise which shows to search first, and which individual files (eg. Episodes) for each show should be downloaded first.

Is there any?

Requirements:

- MacOS 10.13.6
- Open source if possible
- Command line app preferred, but GUI app also possible